# Using crunch to create an Israeli phone numbers list

Tags: crunch

Israeli phone numbers start with 05 and the third digit must be 0, 2, 3, 4, 5 or 8. The fourth and later can be any digit.

I wrote this command:

```
crunch 10 10 0123456789 -o phone_numbers -t 05@@@@@@@@
```

but in my command the third character is not limited.
I don't know how o limit the third character to be only `0`/`2`/`3`/`4`/`5`/`8`. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 2):

The [manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/man1/crunch.1.html) is somewhat misleading. It states:

> ```
> crunch <min-len> <max-len> [<charset string>] [options]
> ```
>
> […]
>
> `charset string`
> You may specify character sets for crunch to use on the  command  line  or  if  you leave it blank crunch will use the default character sets.  The order MUST BE lower case characters, upper case characters, numbers, and then symbols. […]
>
> […]
>
> `-t @,%^`
> Specifies a pattern, eg: `@@god@@@@` where the only the `@`'s, `,`'s, `%`'s, and  `^`'s  will change.
>
> - `@` will insert lower case characters
> - `,` will insert upper case characters
> - `%` will insert numbers
> - `^` will insert symbols

Important fact: where the manual says "lower case characters", "upper case characters", "numbers", and "symbols", it could say "set 1", "set 2", "set 3" and "set 4". The default sets correspond to the terms the manual uses, respectively, but aside from this "lower case characters" is just an abstract "set 1". In this context `@` refers to "set 1" and `%` refers to "set 3".

You defined the first set as `0123456789`, these are not lower case characters, yet it works. The tool doesn't check if "set 1" or "lower case characters" are indeed lower case characters.

Now you need an additional set, a limited one. Let's redefine "upper case characters" ("set 2"):

```
crunch 10 10 0123456789 023458 -o phone_numbers -t 05,@@@@@@@
```

And that's it. Now the third character of the output is generated from an independent set.